# How do I get access to parts of my url/path in a tornado request handler

Tags: python, parsing, routes, httprequest, tornado

Sorry if this question seems basic, but I don't know how to google for what I want, so some explanation is required.

I am using [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/index.html) for my server/routing. Here is what I am attempting to do.

```
http = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/myroute/*", request_handlers.MyHandler, {}),
    (r"/",  request_handlers.defaultHandler, {}),
], **settings)
http.listen(port)
```

So to explain this, whenever a route beginning with "/myroute/" is called, whatever is immediately after the 2nd slash will be interpreted as the required 2nd portion of the path. This value can be empty string.

Some example of paths that I would need to be able to parse...

```
"/myroute/?var1=foo&var2=bar"    ## the required portion is empty string
"/myroute/something?var1=foo"     ## the required portion is "something"
"/myroute/something"             ## same, without options
```

Now in my request handler, I am able to access my options pretty easily.

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        var1 = self.get_argument('var1')
        print var1       ## 'foo'
        var2 = self.get_argument('var2')
        print var2       ## 'bar'
```

Basically, several questions.

1) However, how would I also access the "something" portion of the path, if we are sticking with my example?

2) Is there better terminology for what I am looking for? I have no doubt this is googleable if I only knew what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tornado gives you access to the path with `self.request.path`. You can then split it up into the path components.

Let's say your path is `/myroute/something`.

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        components = [x for x in self.request.path.split("/") if x]
        # results in ['myroute', 'something']
```

Comment: thank you, I ended up going with this for the time being. you get the accept for now

Answer (score 4):

You can specify route with matches (regex) when you add handler to Application:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class SomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, matched_part=None):
        # if route won't match we set param to None

        # different request params that my be handy for you  
        print('Host: %s' % self.request.host)
        print('Entire uri: %s' % self.request.uri)
        print('Uri path: %s' % self.request.path)
        print('Query path w/o ?: %s' % self.request.query)

        if matched_part is None:
            print('Nothing matched')
        else:
            print('Matched part %s' % matched_part)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        # match everything, but query part, after /myroute/ e.g.
        # /myroute/ => None
        # /myroute/test => test
        # /myroute/test/aaa => test/aaa
        # /myroute/test?ss=324 => test            
        ("^\/myroute\/(.+)$", SomeHandler),
        ("/.*", SomeHandler),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I had already implemented jumbopap's response by the time I read this, so he/she ended up with the accept. This seems to be more the spirit of what I was asking though, so I do appreciate you leaving the answer. Might come back to this when I refactor.

Comment: In case anyone is confused as to why "matched_part" does not appear in the tornado doc's... It's actually called [path_args](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.path_args)